# Why can't I mount this disk?

Tags: debian, mount, arm, ntfs

I'm trying to mount an external HDD to an ARM server running Debian Jessie. I removed the partition and made a new one in parted with `mkpart primary ntfs 0% 100%`. Below is the output from `sudo fdisk -l` relevant to the disk and the output when I tried mounting it. Distro and all packages are up-to-date. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 7.3 TiB, 8001563221504 bytes, 15628053167 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BC80D810-2ABA-4F4D-B552-B3017B3AE61A

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 15628052479 15628050432  7.3T Microsoft basic data

root@odroid-jessie:~# mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /media/USBHDD1
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
root@odroid-jessie:~# dmesg | tail
[  378.407567] [c3] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  378.408174] [c3] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  378.418366] [c3] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  378.505027] [c3]  sdb: sdb2
[  378.512752] [c3] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  378.520375] [c1] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  822.494479] [c1] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  822.574393] [c2]  sda: sda1
[  840.166662] [c3] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  840.243315] [c3]  sdb: sdb1
```

Comment: Is `ntfs-3g`installed?

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a partition, it does not add a file-system.

You need to add a file-system, also.

`mkfs.ntfs /dev/sda1` (double check device, if you get it wrong, then you will lose data).

There are partition tools that do both partitioning and creation of file-system.

Comment: I thought parted did this when you specify a fs type.

Comment: @jordanm Some partition editors do, some don't. The actual partition editing does not do it. However some programs do both. So will depend on what program you use.

Comment: I thought parted did this as well. It even asked for filesystem type when I created a partition on another disk; for this one, I specified the filesystem in the command. I’ll try running this when I get home.

Comment: This worked, but it took 32 hours. I now know to use the `-f` flag next time. Thank you!

Comment: 32 hours (Wow).